# Python client socket can't receive data from a successful response

Tags: python, http, sockets

Socket can't receive any data from the server, when there is a successful response, but with bad requests it can. Also server responds, just the socket can't receive data (checked in WireShark)

```
import socket
import ssl

HOST, PORT = 'example.com', 443

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ssock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
ssock.connect((HOST, PORT))

raw_req = [f'GET / HTTP/1.1', 'Host: {HOST}', 'Connection: keep-alive']
req = '\n'.join(raw_req)

ssock.send(req.encode())

msg = ssock.recv(4096).decode()
print(msg)

ssock.close()
```

Comment: Python has an HTTP library that handles all of these details for you, so why are you using the underlying socket library instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I really like low-level network programming, because of it's opportunities, as an example, you can interact with any protocol, which is sends through the network, whether it is well-known http or some strange stuff like quic, i find an advantage in knowing of how it works down there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the [HTTP GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5) expects a sequence of CR LF characters after each header line not just a single '\n' character and an extra CR LF after the last header line. Also, the join() adds the separator between each pair but not at the end so must append data with CR LF + CR LF to be a valid HTTP request.

Second, the `'Host: {HOST}'` must be a f-string otherwise the "{HOST}" is not replaced.

```python
import socket
import ssl

HOST, PORT = 'stackoverflow.com', 443

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    ssock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
    ssock.connect((HOST, PORT))

    raw_req = [f'GET / HTTP/1.1', f'Host: {HOST}', 'Connection: keep-alive']
    req = ('\r\n'.join(raw_req) + "\r\n\r\n").encode()
    print("Request:", req)

    ssock.send(req)

    msg = ssock.recv(4096).decode()
    print("\nResponse:")
    print(msg)
```

**Output:**

```
Request: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
```

If the HTTP response is larger than 4096 bytes then you would need to call `ssock.recv()` in a loop until it returns a byte array of length 0.